# How can I allow unprivileged users to shutdown from the panel? (no sudo)

Tags: shutdown, privileges

I set up an old PC with Edubuntu 12.04 for my girls, with an admin account for myself and normal user accounts for both of them. Unfortunately, they are not able to shut down the computer by themselves with this configuration. Choosing shutdown from the (Unity) panel menu will log them out, but that's it. How do I give them shutdown privileges?

Please note that they are 5 and 7 years old and just starting to find their way around a computer. Solutions that would require them to open a terminal and sudo whatever are not helpful -- and I don't want them to be able to sudo anything, anyway. I need the panel menu entry "Shutdown" to work for them.

Comment: Here's the thing: on regular Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity), a standard user account (created from the GUI) ***can*** shut down the computer with the shutdown option...

Comment: Hmm, I'll try and create another account (maybe something went wrong the first time) and try.

Comment: You know, regular Unity allows shutdowns from the login screen (we've had questions on how to disable that!), so I don't think this is something Edubuntu-specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found it: The answer was actually very simple. Another user session was still open. My girls had just switched accounts instead of logging off. Of course, an unprivileged user issuing a shutdown command does not have any right to terminate another user's session, like a 'sudo shutdown' would.